# Template argument deduction fails on MSVC: bug?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2005

The following fails to compile on VC++8.0 complier with an error (I haven't tried it on the latest visual studio complier yet.)

> error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'const
>   char (&)[6]'

```
template <typename T>
inline T const& compare (T const& a, T const& b)
{
    return a < b ? b : a;
}

int main()
{
    ::compare("string1", "string2");
}
```

Inside the function template, it seems strings are `const char (&)[6]`.

As far as i know, when `<` operator is applied, array should be decayed to pointer.
So, could this error be because of a possible bug?

Comment: gcc [compiles](http://ideone.com/WVU4h) this code without any problems, so this must be a bug in MSVC.

Comment: It is unlikely that you want to pass C strings to such a template anyway (to compare their addresses).

Comment: This does look like a bug, MSVC says the type of the expression `a < b ? b : a` is `const char *` but it should be `const char (&)[8]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most certainly a bug in the Microsoft compiler.

Here is one big difference in C and C++.

```
 e0 ? e1 : e2
```

In C++, a *condtional-expression* produces *lvalue*, **unless** at least one of the expressions in the second part (after `'?'`) is an rvalue, while in C, a *conditional-expression* always produces *rvalue*, no matter what. That means, the following code is perfectly valid in C++ but it is an error in C:

```
int a=10, b=20; 
(a<b?a:b) = 100; //ok in C++, but error in C
```

In C++, it would not give any error, precisely because the expression`(a<b?a:b)` is lvalue expression, so as you can put it on the left side of an assignment.

Now coming back to the original question. In your case, `a` and `b` are arrays of type `char (&) [6]`, and the expression `a<b? a : b` should produce an lvalue, as there is no need of *array-to-pointer* conversion. But in Microsoft compiler, it seems there is *array-to-pointer* conversion.

To verify it, one can write this:

```
template <typename T, int N>
inline void f(T const (&a)[N]) {}

template <typename T>
inline T const& compare (T const& a, T const& b)
{
    f(a < b ? b : a); //is the argument `char*` OR `char (&)[6]`?
    return a < b ? b : a;
}
```

And it gives [no error](http://ideone.com/g6kls) either (in GCC), which means the expression which you pass to `f()` is an array, not a pointer.

Comment: Although correct for this situation, your statement about whether a conditional expressions is an _lvalue_ is too strong. Both second and third expressions can be _glvalues_, but the expression may still be a _prvalue_ if they don't have the same types and the conversion of either one of them two a common type doesn't yield a directly bound _glvalue_.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: I think what you said is true for C++11 only, and C++03 doesn't have those concepts. My post is about C++03, as the OP is using MSVS 2008 which didn't implement C++11 features.

Comment: Well obviously, you have to read _lvalue_ for _glvalue_ and _rvalue_ for _prvalue_, but fundamentally this was still true in C++03.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as i know, when `<` operator is applied, array should be decayed to pointer.

That's the problem, it is being decayed into a `const char *` but then it is trying to convert that into `const char [8]` for the return value.

I'm not sure what the standard says about this, but if you change it to either:

```
compare<char *>("string1","string2");
```

or

```
compare(static_cast<const char *>("string1"),static_const<const char *>("string2"));
```

Then the template parameter `T` will be `char *` instead `char [8]`.